# Flutter populating data in DropDown from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning flutter and followed a tutorial to populate data in dropdownlist from firebase FireStore. But during the process I am getting error :

> Another exception was thrown: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

I am attaching the code, please let me know how to resolve this issue.

```
//Code Above
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: repository.getStream(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData)
                    return const Center(
                      child: const CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
                    );

                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: new DropdownButton(
                      value: _dropdownValue,
                      isDense: true,
                      items:
                          snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                        return new DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                            value: doc.data["classid"] as int,
                            child: Text(doc.data["className"]));
                      }).toList(),
                      hint: Text("Choose Class"),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _dropdownValue = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
//Code Below
```

I found out that the error is firing from :

> child: Text(doc.data["className"]));

this line, and to test, I changed it to Text("Sample"), then it gave error on line above

> value: doc.data["classid"] as int,

Error :

> Another exception was thrown: There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 0.

Database: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is saying that `doc.data["className"]` is null. Check your firestore and make sure that all the documents that you are loading have value on `className` field.

The second error indicates that you have multiple documents with the same value of `doc.data["classid"]`. Every value of `DropdownMenuItem` have to be unique, so make sure that you don't have same `classid` in any of the documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child:  DropdownButton(
                      value: _chosenValue,
                      isDense: true,
                      items:
                          snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                        return  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                           value: doc.data['title'],
                            child: Text(doc.data['title']));
                      }).toList(),
                      hint: Text("Choose Category"),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _chosenValue = value as String?;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  );
```